Simple timeline chart in Google Spreadsheet
I have data that that looks as following:



Username
session_start
session_end




Scott
2020-08-07 20:10:00
2020-08-07 20:50:00


Scott
2020-08-07 22:00:00
2020-08-07 22:07:00


Scott
2020-08-07 22:25:00
2020-08-07 22:30:00


Bob
2020-08-07 20:12:00
2020-08-07 20:30:00


Bob
2020-08-07 20:50:00
2020-08-07 21:11:00


Angela
2020-08-07 20:10:00
2020-08-07 20:57:00



I need to create a time chart in Google Spreadsheet where each username is on the Y-axis and the time line is on the X-axis. The plot line on this chart should span the session_start and session_end timestamps.
How do I plot this in Google Spreadsheet?

Based on your data it isn't clear what you are looking for.  Please provide a visual example of what you want. For example, I can see a Line chart like this (image) making sense but I don't see how a Timeline chart (2 examples) would apply to your data..

@Blindspots I am looking for something like this: https://www.alamy.com/infographic-template-for-business-modern-timeline-diagram-calendar-with-gantt-chart-presentation-vector-infographic-image414125737.html?imageid=B5BEC7D2-2F65-4D1A-AE6C-D6825629D619&p=1276423&pn=1&searchId=287a7f346b0b3aa72aaa6534b852baf9&searchtype=0

@сакибали, not sure it's possible. But you want it for one day or else for what time period should the timeline lines run?

I think you can simulate this with conditional formatting or would need to script something. You shared a Gant chart timeline which is not a Timeline chart as Sheets defines it. What are you using it for?

@Blindspots the goal is visualize overlapping sessions across users i.e. we want to display that Bob and Scott were logged into the app at the same time, even if for a small period of time.

How many users, over how many hours. Is that a realistic data set? This is gonna be a bit of Macguyver-ing so best to look at a realistic use case.  If it isn't, can you mockup some better test data. You can use Blank sheet Maker to share anonymously. Read more about it here.

@Blindspots this is real data. The sessions we will look at a time will span 2 days. There number of users will range from 10-30 users per account. We will be only looking one account at a time

Does it need to be a picture? Is there some metrics (reporting) that would address the need? Just asking not arguing.

2 days range, and how much per range (I don't think it makes sense technically to calculate every minute)? You probably need an idea like this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tt5B1Y6-pajrdDmtYknqPCImidNihuBXTO00XPIDzyY/edit?gid=249819934#gid=249819934 or this https://www.spreadsheetwise.com/post/creating-a-gantt-chart-in-google-sheets

You can create something like that using Conditional Formatting on Google Sheets. It can likely be refined even further, but this should be a good start.
In the example, the session data is in sheet name List of Sessions, and we are looking to generate such a chart for a span of two days per hour, showing for each hour of the day which employee had a session within that (even not the full) hour

In the new (Timeline) sheet in A1 use =UNIQUE('List of Sessions'!A:A) to get a list of names
In B1 enter 8/7/2020 0:00:00 and in C1 enter 8/7/2020 1:00:00, and select both, then drag fill to more columns up to where you want to calculate (and you can set the cell formatting to time only)
In B2 enter the formula: =ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(('List of Sessions'!$A$2:$A=$A2)*('List of Sessions'!$B$2:$B<B$1+TIME(0,30,0))*('List of Sessions'!$C$2:$C>B$1))>0) and drag fill all columns and rows. This will show TRUE for all time slots that this name had a session in (you can set the text color to white so the FALSE/TRUE aren't visible)
Select all those FALSE/TRUE cells and go to Format>Conditional Formatting, and set a color for when Is equal to: TRUE

See example sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MHvfqjbj2ZCRxmcTBJfXYwzBlSPOWI4NjfImh-JbI20/edit


I think you nailed it
